# Inheriting Collection Generics in Java, problem

Tags: java

I've got a compiling problem working with Generics in Java

```
  public class Subject<T>{
  private  long id;
    private T data;
//..
    public T getData() {

        return this.data;

    }

}

    import com.res.emorobots.observer.OrdersIterableObserver;

public class OrdersIterableSubject<T1 extends Collection<OrdersIterableObserver<T2>> ,T2 extends Collection<Order>> extends Subject<Collection<OrdersIterableObserver<T2>>>{

    private  long id;
    private T2 data;
   protected T1  observers;

    public T2 getData() {

        return  this.data;

    }

}
```

Error:
Multiple markers at this line
    - The return type is incompatible with Subject>>.getData()
    - overrides 
     com.res.emorobots.subject.Subject>>.getData

Any Idea? Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

`OrdersIterableSubject` extends `Subject<Collection<OrdersIterableObserver<T2>>>`, so its `getData` method has to return:

```
Collection<OrdersIterableObserver<T2>>
```

(Or a subtype)